# How to handle looping to create file using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have INI file and I want to get specific section. The items in the section that I choose are 24 items. I want to use all the item to write in a file. I tried this, It works, but it looks like bad way to write 24 times to do the process. Is there any other way to do that more beautiful? The section of my INI file like this

Input ini:

```
[Code]
A1=12,34,56
A2=23,45,67
A3=34,56,78,9,10
...
A24=a1,b2,c3,d4,e5
```

Script:

```
Function F_ML
{
    $FilePath = "C:\Users\File.ini"
    $section = "Code"
    $R_1 = "A1"
    $R_2 = "A2"
    $R_3 = "A3"
    $R_4 = "A4"
    $R_5 = "A5"
    $R_6 = "A6"
    $R_7 = "A7"
    $R_8 = "A8"
    $R_9 = "A9"
    $R_10 = "A10"
    $R_11 = "A11"
    $R_12 = "A12"
    $R_13 = "A13"
    $R_14 = "A14"
    $R_15 = "A15"
    $R_16 = "A16"
    $R_17 = "A17"
    $R_18 = "A18"
    $R_19 = "A19"
    $R_20 = "A20"
    $R_21 = "A21"
    $R_22 = "A22"
    $R_23 = "A23"
    $R_24 = "A24"

    $store = "C:\Users\"

    $FilePath
    $input_file = $FilePath
    $ini_file = @{}

    Get-Content $input_file | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Trim()
    } | Where-Object {


    $_ -notmatch '^(;|$)'
    } | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^\[.*\]$') {
        $section = $_ -replace '\[|\]'
        $ini_file[$section] = @{}
    } else {
        $key, $value = $_ -split '\s*=\s*', 2
        $ini_file[$section][$key] = $value
    }
    }

     #--------
     $Path_Store = $store
     #---------
     $Get_1 = $ini_file.($section).($R_1)
     $L_1 = $Get_1.Substring(0,3)

     $Get_2 = $ini_file.($section).($R_2)
     $L_2 = $Get_2.Substring(0,3)

     $Get_3 = $ini_file.($section).($R_3)
     $L_3 = $Get_3.Substring(0,3)


     #---------
     $Outer = ";********************"
     $Header = ";*******************"
     $ML = "12345"
     $FB = ";Initial=1a2b"
     #----------
     $B_ID_1 = ";Build=" + $ML + "#" + "S" + $L_1 + "#" + "D" + $L_1
     $CRM_1 = ";CRM="  + $R_1
     $Output_1 = $Header, $B_ID_1, $FB, $CRM_1 , $Outer | Out-File $Path_Store\A1

     $B_ID_2 = ";Build=" + $ML + "#" + "S" + $L_2 + "#" + "D" + $L_2
     $CRM_2 = ";CRM="  + $R_2
     $Output_2 = $Header, $B_ID_2, $FB, $CRM_2 , $Outer | Out-File $Path_Store\A2

     $B_ID_3 = ";Build=" + $ML + "#" + "S" + $L_3 + "#" + "D" + $L_3
     $CRM_3 = ";CRM="  + $R_3
     $Output_3 = $Header, $B_ID_3, $FB, $CRM_3 , $Outer | Out-File $Path_Store\A3


     #---------
    }

    $call = F_ML
```

My expectation, I can make this way shorter and the output is getting 24 output file.

```
Output Sample
Output File 1
;********************
;Build=12345#S12#D12
;Initial=1a2b
;CRM=A1
;********************

Output File 2
;********************
;Build=12345#S23#D23
;Initial=1a2b
;CRM=A2
;********************
```

Comment: What is  `"Build=12345"` and `"Initial=1a2b"` here. Your script has it hardcoded and the only things dynamic here are `CRM=<value>` and #S<value>D<value>`. Will `Build` and `Initial` always be same for all files ?

Comment: It just a string. Yes, It will be always same for all files. @PrasoonKarunanV

Answer (score 0):

Try below...

```
$IniContent = Get-Content -Path $IninPath
$IniContent | ForEach-Object -Process {
  $Split          = $_ -split '=';
  $OutPutfilePath = "c:\temp\$($Split[0]).txt"
  $first          = ($Split[1] -split ',')[0]
  $append         = "#S{0}D{1}" -f $first,$first

  # create a herestring to build the output
  @"
  ;********************
  ;Build=$Ml$append
  $FB
  ;CRM=$($Split[0])    
  ;********************
  "@ | Out-File -Path $OutPutfilePath -Force
 }
```

Comment: its not consider to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ForEach` to manipulate a string and `Invoke` the `Expression`.

```
1..24 | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Expression -Command (
    '$R_{0} = "A{0}"' -f $_
)}
.
.
.
1..24 | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Expression -Command (
    '$Get_{0} = $ini_file.($section).($R_{0}) `
     $L_{0} = $Get_{0}.Substring(0,3)' -f $_
)}
.
.
.
1..24 | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Expression -Command (
    '$B_ID_{0} = ";Build=" + $ML + "#" + "S" + $L_{0} + "#" + "D" + $L_{0}
     $CRM_{0} = ";CRM="  + $R_{0}
     $Output_{0} = $Header, $B_ID_{0}, $FB, $CRM_{0} , $Outer | Out-File $Path_Store\A{0}' -f $_
)}
```

`{0}` will be replaced by the value behind `-f` so it will be replaced `Foreach` number from 1 to 24...

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

All I did here was use your existing code to run everything in a loop from 1 to 24, removing the duplicated code. I reformatted it a little so it was a little easier for me to read.

Essentially, the variable `$i` will be a number from `1` to `24`, while the variable `$R` will be "`A`" and whatever number is in `$i` (essentially `A` + `$i`)

```
Function F_ML
{
    $section = "Code"
    $store = "C:\Users\"
    $input_file = "C:\Users\File.ini"
    $ini_file = @{}

    for ($i=1; $i -le 24; $i++) 
    {
        $R = "A$($i)"

        Get-Content $input_file | 

        ForEach-Object `
        {
            $_.Trim()
        } | 

        Where-Object `
        {
            $_ -notmatch '^(;|$)'
        } | 

        ForEach-Object `
        {
            if ($_ -match '^\[.*\]$') 
            {
                $section = $_ -replace '\[|\]'
                $ini_file[$section] = @{}
            } 

            else 
            {
                $key, $value = $_ -split '\s*=\s*', 2
                $ini_file[$section][$key] = $value
            }
        }

         #--------
         $Path_Store = $store
         #---------
         $Get = $ini_file.($section).($R)
         $L = $Get.Substring(0,3)

         #---------
         $Outer = ";********************"
         $Header = ";*******************"
         $ML = "12345"
         $FB = ";Initial=1a2b"
         #----------
         $B_ID = ";Build=" + $ML + "#" + "S" + $L + "#" + "D" + $L
         $CRM = ";CRM="  + $R
         $Output = $Header, $B_ID, $FB, $CRM , $Outer | Out-File $Path_Store\$R
    }
}
```